# Spring boot 2 Post required type exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, controller, thymeleaf

I am trying to learn spring-boot but i have one issue that I do not understand how to solve and what is specifically failing. I have a blog, and when in blog post form I try to create a new post (article) it fails. Please if possible help me to get on road and understand what's the issue, because i can't see where conversion is made wrong.

Expected behavior: New post row is added to database

Current behavior: I got Errortype mismatch.

Error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIUbH.png)

Post.class

```
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "post_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
@Length(min = 5, message = "*Pavadinimas turi turėti bent 5 simbolius")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Įrašykite pavadinimą")
private String title;

@Column(name = "body", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String body;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "create_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
@CreationTimestamp
private Date createDate;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false)
@NotNull
private User user;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Collection<Comment> comments;
```

User.class

```
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false)
@Email(message = "*Netinkamas El. Pašto formatas")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Įrašykite El. Paštą")
private String email;

@Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
@Length(min = 5, message = "*Slapyvardis turi turėti bent 5 simbolius")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Įrašykite slapyvardį")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
@Length(min = 5, message = "*Slaptažodis turi turėti bent 5 simbolius")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Įrašykite slaptažodį")
@JsonIgnore
private String password;

@Column(name = "name")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Įrašykite savo vardą")
private String name;

@Column(name = "last_name")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Įrašykite savo pavardę")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "profession")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Pasirinkite savo profesija")
private String profession;

@Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
private boolean active;

@Column(name = "tenant", nullable = false)
private String tenant;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Collection<Role> roles;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Collection<Post> posts;
```

}

PostController

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/newPost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createNewPost(@Valid Post post,
                            BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        for (Object object : bindingResult.getAllErrors()) {
            if (object instanceof FieldError) {
                FieldError fieldError = (FieldError) object;

                System.out.println("Field Error "+fieldError.getCode()+"\n");
                System.out.println(fieldError.getObjectName()+"\n");
                System.out.println(fieldError.getDefaultMessage()+"\n");
            }

            if (object instanceof ObjectError) {
                ObjectError objectError = (ObjectError) object;

                System.out.println("Object Error"+objectError.getCode());
                System.out.println(objectError.getObjectName()+"\n");
                System.out.println(objectError.getDefaultMessage()+"\n");
            }
        }
        return "/postForm";
    } else {
        postService.save(post);
        return "redirect:/blog/" + post.getUser().getUsername();
    }
}
```

Post view

```
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center" style="margin-top:20px">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
            <form autocomplete="off" action="#" th:action="@{/newPost}"
                  th:object="${post}" method="post" class="form-horizontal"
                  role="form">

                <h2 class="text-center">Jūsų naujas straipsnis</h2>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('title')}" th:errors="*{title}"
                           class="alert alert-danger"></label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{title}" placeholder="Pavadinimas"
                           class="form-control input-lg"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('body')}" th:errors="*{body}"
                           class="alert alert-danger"></label>
                    <textarea th:field="*{body}" placeholder="Tekstas"
                              class="form-control input-lg"/>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{user}"/>
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Saugoti"/>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" th:if="${post.id}">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form action="#" th:action="@{'/post/{id}'(id=${post.id})}" th:method="delete"
                  class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" th:text="Ištrinti">Ištrinti</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

GitHub repository: https://github.com/Manvas/mentor/tree/develop

Comment: Please share post json and postService.save(post)  code.

Comment: Also share User entity class and service class to save as seems issue is with id you are passing for USer object might be data type issue between your entity and many to many table entity

Answer (score 0):

Your problem basically is with the user parameter inside Post object. You are sending user info to the view and keep it hidden, but you cant use an input field for that.

This is the line which is wrong

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{user}"/>
```

And you should use a primitive value, in this case the user ID.

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{user.id}"/>
```

Then when you receive the post again you will have access to the user Id and all user info. If you need to modify some user specific info then access to them by user.XX and read it in the post method